# Instance type for AWS Spark EMR Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to pick an instance type for my Spark EMR clusters.  I was wondering if anyone ever runs these types of clusters with EBS-only instances?  By this I mean instance types such as r5.2xlarge which does not have local disk. It strikes me as a bad idea, but I thought I'd check here to see if I am missing anything.

I am thinking of using r5d.2xlarge for masters and slaves as sort of a general mix of compute, memory, and local storage for general workloads.  Sound reasonable?  My use case is to host a jupyter notebook interface for Spark which will do a wide variety of analytics, so I can't really pin down the precise workload beyond that in a description for you to review because I will end up doing ad-hoc analysis with this.  Some analysis will involve large joins of two or more data sets, however.

Thanks,

Setjmp

Answer (score 0):

If you need local storage you can rely on [r3](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/previous-generation/) instances, they come with pretty large instance storage, which is used for HDFS,  and I think they are cheaper. But currently you can store mostly everything on S3. I would recommend to [configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-s3.html) S3 persistence for Jupiter notebooks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is no instance storage, you can easily attach the EBS. During the creation of EMR cluster, there is a step to select the amount of EBS in advanced mode. So the storage is not a problem I think.

[image]